# Get rid of temp tables in SQL statement

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I have been asked to "get rid of" temp tables in my SQL statement, I have tried everything but I'm quite rookie, can someone help me with this? I need to keep final result the same because I use final statement to fill cursor.

```sql
/* build support temp tables from info mart schema */
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME AS META,    
    SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 1, LEN(TABLE_NAME) - 5) AS BASENAME 
INTO 
    #TNS_META
FROM 
    [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME LIKE '%0_META%'
        
        
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME AS MEAS, 
    SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 1, LEN(TABLE_NAME) - 5) AS BASENAME
INTO 
    #TNS_MEAS
FROM 
    [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME LIKE '%0_MEAS%'

/* final support table */
SELECT DISTINCT 
    #TNS_META.TABLE_SCHEMA, MEAS, META
FROM 
    #TNS_MEAS
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    #TNS_META ON #TNS_META.BASENAME = #TNS_MEAS.BASENAME
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use CTE?

Comment: Just DROP TABLE #... after your cursor loop..

Comment: Yes I'm allowed to use CTE.

Comment: Thank you, @rajorshi for your hint I rewrite it using CTE and it works as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [IM_DM12]

;
WITH META (TABLE_SCHEMA, META, BASENAME)
AS

(

    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME AS META, SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,1,LEN(TABLE_NAME)-5) AS BASENAME
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%0_META%'
)
,

MEAS (TABLE_SCHEMA, MEAS, BASENAME)
AS

(

    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME AS MEAS, SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,1,LEN(TABLE_NAME)-5) AS BASENAME
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%0_MEAS%'

)

SELECT DISTINCT META.TABLE_SCHEMA, MEAS, META
FROM MEAS
FULL OUTER JOIN META ON META.BASENAME = MEAS.BASENAME
ORDER BY META.TABLE_SCHEMA;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).